# What does it mean to in this ANOVA table, describe its direction, magnitude, and statistical significance?

Tags: statistics

The following table shows the results of an ANOVA testing the relationship between class and years of education using all of the respondents in 2012. How does one interpret these results? It states that the relationship between social class and average years of education is using α=.01

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRPJv.jpg)

What is the direction, magnitude and statistical significance? I am confused on how this terms would apply to the table.

Please help Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are talking about the variance of the test. Its magnitude is given under the column heading MS with F as the ratio of the two. That is, inter class variability and between class variability. The direction is obvious, higher class = more years of education and the significance can be summarized by stating the p value = 0 and rejecting the null, hence there is a significant difference in the number of years of education etc etc.

Comment: Thanks, what did they mean by the direction and statistical significance?

Comment: A result is statistically significant if the p value is less than alpha. So this result is statistically significant because p = 0 < alpha = .01. I took direction to mean the trend of the relationship between class and years with the trend being positive in the direction of the higher the class the more years of education.

Comment: Thanks once more!Just one last question, what are these values actually telling us? We have the magnitude of variabillity within groups being 610.858 and the magnitude of variability between groups: 8.7197, but what does these numbers actually tell us objectively about anything? I don't quite understand what it means for something "BETWEEN GROUPS" "WITHIN GROUPS" could you please explain the meaning and the meaning of these words and the meaning behind the numbers, they are just numbers to me right now ha.

Comment: The variance has been measured, which is the spread of the number of years of education, within a single (within groups), and across all groups (between groups). There is an obvious difference with a much larger spread between groups. Mathematically, the variance is the square of the standard deviation and is the average sum of the squared distances from the mean. That is, find the mean of the group, then take every value and determine its distance from the mean and square it, and add them all together and divide by the number of data values. That's variance. The square root of that is std dev

Comment: Thank you! It is much appreciated!